# Material table not updating data after an insert

Tags: angular, angular-material

I got a component data that holds the material table and other one that holds the form component. When first starts the app list all items correctly but after an insert the table is not updating automatically only when the page is refreshed. The data is retrieved from person.service

My Form.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Person } from '../person/person.model';
import { MatSnackBar, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { PersonService } from '../person/person.service';
import { DataComponent } from '../tableData/data.component';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Output() addedPerson = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @ViewChild(DataComponent, { static: false }) dataComponent: DataComponent;

  newPerson: Person = new Person();
  // editedPerson: Person;


  nameFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  lastNameFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);
  phoneFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);



  constructor(public snackbar: MatSnackBar, private personService: PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() { }

  savePerson() {
    this.personService.addPerson(this.newPerson).subscribe(response => {
      this.snackbar.open('Usuario Agregado', null, { duration: 2000 });
      this.clear();
      this.personService.getPersonsList().subscribe(list => {
        this.dataComponent.dataSource = list;
      });
    });
  }

  // CLEAR ALL INPUTS
  clear() {
    this.newPerson.name = '';
    this.nameFormControl.clearValidators();
    this.newPerson.lastName = '';
    this.lastNameFormControl.clearValidators();
    this.newPerson.email = '';
    this.emailFormControl.clearValidators();
    this.newPerson.phone = '';
    this.phoneFormControl.clearValidators();
  }
}
```

My data.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from '../person/person.model';
import { PersonService } from '../person/person.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.css']
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource;
  // displayedColumns: string[] = ['Id', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'email', 'telefono', 'acciones'];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['nombre', 'apellido', 'email', 'telefono', 'acciones'];
  @ViewChild('dataTable', { static: false }) dataTable;
  // @Output() sendDataBack = new EventEmitter<{ index, name, lastName, email, phone }>();

  constructor(private personService: PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.personService.getPersonsList().subscribe(
      personsList => {
        this.dataSource = personsList;
        console.log(personsList);
      });
  }

  editPerson(element) {
    // this.sendDataBack.emit({
    //   index: this.dataSource.indexOf(element),
    //   name: element.name, lastName: element.lastName, email: element.email, phone: element.phone
    // });
  }

  deletePerson(element) {
    // this.dataSource.splice(element.index, 1);
    // this.dataTable.renderRows();
  }

}
```

My person.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from './person.model';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class PersonService {

  private url = 'http://localhost:8080/persons';
  private httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPersonsList(): Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.http.get<Person[]>(this.url);
  }

  addPerson(person: Person): Observable<Person> {
    return this.http.post<Person>(this.url, person, { headers: this.httpHeaders });
  }

}
```

I'm still learning angular so I don't know what am I missing. Thanks in advance

Comment: `getPersonsList` executes once and is done. You would have to use WebSocket to have a stream from server to client. But most likely you just want another service to act as a store to hold the state. Use Subject or BehaviourSubject to hold users and subscribe to it, instead. Thats all I can tell. Quite a bit to cover here

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way to do this by simply calling

```
this.dataComponent.dataTable.dataSource = this.personService.getPersonsList();
```

After emit an event emitter to the app.component.